# Copy Command to insert CSV file - Escape Special Characters

Tags: postgresql, bulkinsert

I am trying to do a bulk insert into postgres db using copy command from csv file. All the columns  in the db table are character_varying(1024) type.The copy command is failing on certain values which are in Double quotes
For example:
"TODD'S JAMES RENO PHCY,INC."

My copy command looks like below:

```
    \copy file_tmp FROM  /srv/data0/transfer/data_2.csv  USING DELIMITERS ','
```

Could you please help in how to escape these special characters and get this working?

Comment: Please show a complete line that fails and the table definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you have specified a delimiter, you have not specified a format, so it is still using "text".  In "text" format, thing are escaped by backslashes, not quotes.

Also, 'USING DELIMITERS' is an extremely obsolete syntax.

You probably want something like:

```
\copy file_tmp FROM  /srv/data0/transfer/data_2.csv  WITH (FORMAT CSV)
```

You don't need to specify the delimiter, because it defaults to ',' when using CSV format.

Of course this still might fail on parts of the data you haven't shown us.